# WPF: Changing MediaElement source with ResourceDictionary

Tags: wpf, mediaelement, resourcedictionary

I want to use background music in my WPF Application.
Like you can see here: [How to do background music for my WPF-Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148965/how-to-do-background-music-for-my-wpf-application)

So I use a MediaElement.

Now I want to change the source of it while running the Application.

I'm already doing something similar with some background pictures. There I have different ResourceDictionaries that I'm switching to show different "themes".

One of my dictionaries looks like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <ImageBrush x:Key="Backgroundpic" ImageSource="picture.png"/>

         ...

</ResourceDictionary>
```

So I can use it in the xaml like this:

```
...
<Grid x:Name="Bg" Background="{DynamicResource Backgroundpic}"/>
...
```

But HOW can I do that with my MediaElement-Source that I can use it like this:

```
 <MediaElement x:Name="myMediaElement" Source="{DynamicResource ???}" />
```

I just don't know what to write into my ResourceDictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Source is a [Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx), so you need your resource to be a Uri.  (Note that System.Uri is in the System assembly, not mscorlib, so it needs a different XML namespace than you would use for types like String):

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System">

    <sys:Uri x:Key="mediaSource">something.mp3</sys:Uri>
```

Then you can reference it with `Source={DynamicResource mediaSource}`.